# English Translation of "Connectivity of Probabilistic Networks"

Tags: reference-request

A seminal paper in network reliability is "Connectivity of Probabilistic Networks" by Kel'mans, with a link [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=at&paperid=10788&option_lang=eng).

However, the linked PDF file is in Russian. Is there an English translation available online? The version journal/year (Automation and Remote Control, 1967, 444–460) listed there does not seem to be available online.

Comment: Springer Link has only [2001 and newer](http://link.springer.com/journal/volumesAndIssues/10513) of the journal online. Google books doesn't have [any previews](https://books.google.com/books/about/Automation_and_Remote_Control.html?id=mW4rAQAAMAAJ) of volume 28. OCLC WorldCat [lists](http://www.worldcat.org/title/automation-and-remote-control/oclc/820926641?referer=di&ht=edition) one physical copy of the volume being held by in Karnal, India. Your chances of finding a digital copy seem slim. Learning to read Russian may take less time than trying to find an English copy.

Comment: @GEL That's extremely unfortunate...but I appreciate what you were able to find!